# Sound for some applications comes from internal speakers, while for others my Bluetooth speaker is used

Tags: sound

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

The sound for VLC and Rhythmbox comes from my Bluetooth speaker but other applications Firefox and Telegram use my internal speaker.

What can I do about this?

Comment: I think your question can be answered okay as it is, but we might be able to help you better if you [edit] and tell us what you want to achieve. Do you want all applications and system sounds to use the Bluetooth speaker, or the internal speaker, or do you just want to know how to control sound output devices in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set default audio output , open the terminal and run:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

You will see names of you output devices, for example:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    name: <bluez_sink.70_26_05_3B_F5_66.a2dp_sink>
```

Then create the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa.d/default-sink.pa` (in Ubuntu 21.10) or edit the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (in Ubuntu 20.04), and paste into it a command:

```
set-default-sink NAME_OF_YOUR_SPEAKER
```

For example

```
set-default-sink bluez_sink.70_26_05_3B_F5_66.a2dp_sink
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Many thanks for your information , I run

Comment: Many thanks for your information , I run pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
 and find my Bluetooth speaker as second line ...and i try to set it as you mention but always make en error which mean ' not find',or maybe I think  need root ?!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to define your Bluetooth device audio as "default audio output"?
If you're using KDE, navigate to volume icon (left to clock) and select Bluetooth speaker device and from the menu select "set as default audio output".